# php regex replace image tags

Tags: php, regex

I need replace image tags with smiles to {smile:smilename}

```
   <?php
    $pattern = '<img src="/img/smile/(.*?).gif">';
    $replacement = '{smile:$1}';
    $subject = '<div contenteditable="true" id="message_text">text<img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"><img src="/img/smile/smile3.gif"></div>';
    echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject, -1 );
    ?>
```

I get:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="message_text">text<{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}><{smile:smile3}></div>
```

- `<{smile:smile3}>`

but i need

- `{smile:smile3}`

Comment: You should parse the HTML first and *then* manipulate the `src` attributes of `img` elements. You're trying to parse HTML with regex, and [that's not a good idea.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/399649)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `<` and `>` are being treated as delimiters, instead of part of the expression. Use:

```
$pattern = '#<img src="/img/smile/(.*?).gif">#';
```

See the php.net [regexp delimiters documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (third code example, and top user note)

Comment: Someone care to explain why they think this correct answer is incorrect?

Comment: My guess is that someone thinks that slashes have to be escaped, or that the delimiter **has** to be a slash which is completely wrong.

Comment: I just realised that < > pair cannot be delimiters, they are different. His code just does not make any sense. It would not work at all.

Comment: Nice catch! Also, +1!

Comment: @h2ooooooo Yea, must be

Comment: @Segabond actually, you can use paired delimiters, not just repeated characters i.e. `[expr]` or `{expr}` not just `/expr/`

Comment: I see. That explains.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a delimiting characters in your pattern and escape this character inside.

```
$pattern = '/<img src="\/img\/smile\/(.*?).gif">/';
```

Or

```
$pattern = '@<img src="/img/smile/(.*?).gif">@';
```